# Practice for learning sequences and series

Tags: sequences-and-series, soft-question, advice

Out of all the single variable calculus topics, I've noticed that sequences and series seems to be the one that gets the most "glossed over" in high school. It's by far my weakest topic, and I was wondering if anyone had some recommendations for sources of problems/readings to help improve.

Comment: A relatively good (and easy to study from) book is Stewart Calculus. It covers the basics of the whole Series topic in one chapter. Solutions manuals are available online as well.

Comment: agree with stewart. larson isn't bad either. for a more rigorous but not too advanced treatment look at Apostol